# Dojo Enhanced grid Set Filter does not retains filter condition applied

Tags: dojo

In my scenario I have set enhanced grid with a filter query (values, conditions, columns and logicany or logicall.

But it works fine with below code except "isempty" condition. On edit or update the filter applied, it does not retains the filter condition applied, instead it takes the first option from condition drop down list.

Here is the code:

```js
grid.setFilter([{
    type: 'string',
    column: 1,
    condition: 'startsWith',
    value: 'XXX'
    }, {
    type: 'number',
    column: 2,
    condition: 'lessthan',
    value: 100
}], 'logicany');
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire code in jsFiddle?

Comment: @Manjunatha Muniyappa...Thanks for your response....Here is the sample, but filter is applied as static. Try to edit or updated the 2nd column filter applied...It does not retains "startsWith" condition already applied. It takes default "contains" condition. http://jsfiddle.net/KDTcC/449/